# How do I run a query that makes table in Access through C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to run query called "MyQuery" that I have in Access that makes a table.

How do I run this query in C# code ?

Comment: What does the "throw" in the question's title mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that means 'through'

Comment: So why doesn't somebody just edit the title, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this thread on vbCity](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/112704.aspx), which seems to be exactly about your problem.

Your code might then look similar to this:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.

using (IDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(...)) // <- add connection string
{
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        // option 1:
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ... FROM MyQuery";

        // option 2:
        command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
        command.CommandText = "MyQuery";

        // option 3:
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "MyQuery";

        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // do something with the result set returned by reader...
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```